# Copying issue with GetStream EnrichedActivity class

Tags: swift, getstream-io

I m trying to implement the Copy protocol on swift so that I can copy the activity. But EnrichedActivity has a property originFeedId that is let. 
And designated initialiser does not take originFeedId parameter.Below is the code for EnrichedActivity initialiser in getStream iOS Pod.

```
    public init(actor: ActorType,
            verb: Verb,
            object: ObjectType,
            foreignId: String? = nil,
            time: Date? = nil,
            feedIds: FeedIds? = nil) {
    self.actor = actor
    self.verb = verb
    self.object = object
    self.foreignId = foreignId
    self.time = time
    self.feedIds = feedIds
    originFeedId = nil
}
```

Comment: Hey Aashish, I'll fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed in version 1.2.1. Please check it.

Comment: All property of Info Struct (ClientError.Info) should be public. I want to check status code but can not access it , because it is internal access level

Comment: For now it has public description with all information, but yes, it's not convenient for the checking status code. It will be public in the next release.